# Pointer making C program to crash

Tags: c, pointers

What is this code doing exactly:

```
char* pointer=0;
*pointer=0;
```

Every time I run this code, the programme crashes!

Comment: lookup dereferencing null pointer

Comment: Apparently, you're referencing memory you've not reserved. 0 is often used as the value for NULL and address 0 is therefore often read and write protected, so writing to that address will in your case crash the program.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: @n.m. I think the question was quite clear. Even with my limited intelligence I was able to work out in 1.254 ms that the OP does not want his program to crash.

Comment: @SzG No program is supposed to crash. What the program is supposed to do, apart from not crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First line: You create a `pointer` variable to a char, then you initialize it to address zero (NULL pointer).

Second line: you try to write a zero to the address where `pointer` is pointing to.
Address zero is outside of your process' writable virtual memory area, so you get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

In your first line of code you declared a char pointer and intialized it to 0. It is nothing but you are making it a NULL pointer.

---

In your second line you are trying to assign a value to NULL pointer so program crashes.